# Create list by using 'Student' class but from the another list with LINQ C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, extension-methods

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

> Using the Student class, create a list of a few students from the people list using LINQ.

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person("John", "Doe", 20),
    new Person("Alex", "Jhones", 18)
};


var students = new List<Student>();

students = people.Select(p => p).ToList();

foreach (var i in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I tried to write the line `students=people.Select(p=>p).ToList();` However, parameter `p` refers to the `Person` class, I need to write something else there so the parameter refers to `Student` class.

```
public sealed class Student
{
    public uint ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Surname { get; }
    public uint Grade { get; }

    public Student(uint id, 
                   string name, 
                   string surname, 
                   uint grade)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Grade = grade;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"Student {ID} named {Name} {Surname} got {Grade}.";
}

public sealed class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; }
    public uint Age { get; }

    public Person(string name, 
                  string surname, 
                  uint age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do the `Student` and the `Person` class look like?

Comment: Whats the relationship between `Student` and `Person`?

Comment: Put the ‍`person‍` and `student` `class` code

Comment: As a hint: you can use `Select(x => ...)` to create a `Student` instance for every `Person` in the list. It does not have to be `Select(p => p)`, but instead transform `p` to something else, like `Select(p => new ...);`.

Comment: @Markus Thank you, Sir, it worked :) here is the code I wrote and seems like it does the job, can you, please, tell if it is what you meant? 
students = people.Select(p => new Student(23, p.Name, p.Surname, 89)).ToList();
I wanted to use name and surname of the people in 'people' list

Comment: @devnewdevv yes, that's exactly what I meant